# ¿Alguien me dice donde puedo descargar SQL server con agent service?

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito descargar SQL Server con agent service para SQL server la verdad descargue del sitio de microsoft. no conozco ningún link de descarga en el que SQL Server tenga el agent service. dejo foto de referencia. a ver si alguno me recomiendo un link. lo ocupo en ingles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo entendido que la versión express (la gratuita) no incluye el agente de sql. En[este enlace](https://spaghettidba.com/2014/01/23/sql-server-agent-in-express-edition/) te explican cómo implementar una herramienta gratuita para sustituir el agente. ¡Suerte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes descargarlo del sitio de [descargas de SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) en Microsoft.

Dicho esto, debes saber que la edición SQL Server Express no incluye soporte para SQL Server Agent.

En cambio, las siguientes ediciones de SQL Server si tienen soporte para el agente:

- Enterprise
- standard
- Developer
- Web

Para más información, consulta la [documentación de SQL Server agent](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017).